# How to REMOVE clock from Login (SDDM) AND Lock Screen KDE Plasma?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, login, kde, lock-screen

I've been rummaging around /usr/share looking for the files to remove the clock from both the Login and Lock screens, but so far nothing has worked, and recently removing the Clock.Qml file from `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/` locked my out of the PC (had to reboot to login).

So before I go completely locking myself out of my PC, how can I completely remove the Clock from both the Lock (SDDM) and Login Screen?

I like the unified look of Breeze for both the Lock and Login, which is why I want to edit them instead of finding a third party option.

I am on ubuntu 20.04 LTS, KDE Plasma 5.18.8, and am using the Breeze (0.1) Login Screen.

Comment: Why not just switch to a `sddm` theme that doesn't include a clock, and looks the way you want it to look. KDE provides great tools to do that.  Your alternative is to edit the theme & remove what annoys you (ie. creating your own version)

Comment: No other theme doesn't include a clock, and fits well with the stock (unchangeable) lock screen. Which is why I am asking what file(s) to edit to remove the clock. Considering I am dealing with the mechanism to get into the computer, I really don't want to mess something up and get permanently locked out.

Comment: Even if you completely screw up the `sddm` theme thus it's impossible to login via GUI; you can still login via text terminal. A couple of cycles ago I did some *bug work-around/experiementation* work on a `sddm` theme issue and it was just editing a text file (QML from memory; I see a `Clock{` in my current theme's `Main.qml`) but given there are >4000 themes (457 easily downloadable via GUI) it's easiest to just use another in my experience.  Download a few & contrast the QML code to see how they work.

Comment: I'll poke around some more, but even downloading another sddm theme, I still have the clock in the lock screen.

Comment: for Lock screen: Settings->Workspace Behavior->Screen Locking->Appearance (Configure...)->Show: Clock. Sorry, if it's not there, I'm running currently Kubuntu 21.

Comment: Yeah, I have show clock unchecked, yet it still appears.